# Unable to use the Linux service to start Archiva 2.1.0

Tags: linux, archiva

I'm trying to start the recently published Apache Archiva v2.1.0 (Standalone) on Linux.

For testing purpose, the zip has been uncompressed in **/opt/archiva-2.0**.

The docs says:
http://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/adminguide/standalone.html

> On Linux, the bin/archiva script is suitable for linking or copying to
>   /etc/init.d/archiva and running as root, as long as the RUN_AS_USER
>   environment variable is set within the script.

So I've copied the **/opt/archiva-2.0/bin/archiva** Shell script in **/opt/init.d**.

I tried with both:

```
#RUN_AS_USER=root
```

and

```
RUN_AS_USER=root
```

but I always get the same error at startup:

```
>service archiva console
/etc
Unable to locate any of the following operational binaries:
  /etc/rc.d/init.d/./wrapper-linux-x86-64
  /etc/rc.d/init.d/./wrapper-linux-x86-32
  /etc/rc.d/init.d/./wrapper
```

For information:

```
>uname -a
Linux ****** 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Making symbolic link of the bin/archiva script to /etc/init.d/archiva works better and that way the script is just in one place.

```
$ ln -s /opt/archiva-2.0/bin/archiva /etc/init.d/archiva
```