# Unable to start Archiva v2.1.0 on Linux - java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: linux, archiva

I'm trying the latest release of Archiva (v2.1.0).
As I've mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158880/unable-to-use-the-linux-service-to-start-archiva-2-1-0), I'm having issue to start Archiva using the service, so I've started it directly in its installation folder using the following command:

```
/opt/archiva-2.0/bin/archiva start
```

Everything looks fine:

```
Starting Apache Archiva...
```

But in /opt/archiva-2.0/logs/wrapper-20140806.log, I get a **java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError**:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/08/06 13:13:35 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/08/06 13:13:36 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:36 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:36 |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:36 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:36 | 2014-08-06 13:13:36.763:WARN:oejd.ContextDeployer:ContextDeployer is deprecated. Use ContextProvider
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:36 | 2014-08-06 13:13:36.769:WARN:oejd.WebAppDeployer:WebAppDeployer is deprecated. Use WebAppProvider
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:36 | 2014-08-06 13:13:36.885:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:36 | 2014-08-06 13:13:36.905:INFO:oejs.NCSARequestLog:Opened /opt/archiva-2.0/logs/request-20140806.log
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:36 | 2014-08-06 13:13:36.952:INFO:oejd.ContextDeployer:Deploy /opt/archiva-2.0/contexts/archiva.xml -> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,null},/opt/archiva-2.0/apps/archiva
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 | 2014-08-06 13:13:39.526:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 | 2014-08-06 13:13:39.602:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 | 2014-08-06 13:13:39.640:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/opt/archiva-2.0/apps/archiva/},/opt/archiva-2.0/apps/archiva
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 | java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:85)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:72)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:367)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.deploy(ContextDeployer.java:359)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.access$000(ContextDeployer.java:82)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer$ScannerListener.fileAdded(ContextDeployer.java:107)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:336)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.doStart(ContextDeployer.java:421)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1274)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1197)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 | Caused by: 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 | java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/archiva/web/startup/ArchivaStartup : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:421)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1528)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitListener(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1893)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:85)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:72)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:367)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.deploy(ContextDeployer.java:359)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.access$000(ContextDeployer.java:82)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer$ScannerListener.fileAdded(ContextDeployer.java:107)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:336)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.doStart(ContextDeployer.java:421)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1274)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1197)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:13:39 | 2014-08-06 13:13:39.656:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/08/06 13:19:27 | TERM trapped.  Shutting down.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:28 | 2014-08-06 13:19:28.342:INFO:oejs.Server:Graceful shutdown SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:28 | 2014-08-06 13:19:28.343:INFO:oejs.Server:Graceful shutdown o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/opt/archiva-2.0/apps/archiva/},/opt/archiva-2.0/apps/archiva
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:29 | 2014-08-06 13:19:29.371:INFO:/:Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:30 | 2014-08-06 13:19:30.201:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/opt/archiva-2.0/apps/archiva/},/opt/archiva-2.0/apps/archiva
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/08/06 13:19:30 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/08/06 13:19:34 | --> Wrapper Started as Daemon
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/08/06 13:19:34 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:34 | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:34 |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:34 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:35 | 2014-08-06 13:19:35.411:WARN:oejd.ContextDeployer:ContextDeployer is deprecated. Use ContextProvider
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:35 | 2014-08-06 13:19:35.415:WARN:oejd.WebAppDeployer:WebAppDeployer is deprecated. Use WebAppProvider
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:35 | 2014-08-06 13:19:35.502:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:35 | 2014-08-06 13:19:35.514:INFO:oejs.NCSARequestLog:Opened /opt/archiva-2.0/logs/request-20140806.log
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:35 | 2014-08-06 13:19:35.543:INFO:oejd.ContextDeployer:Deploy /opt/archiva-2.0/contexts/archiva.xml -> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,null},/opt/archiva-2.0/apps/archiva
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 | 2014-08-06 13:19:38.608:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 | 2014-08-06 13:19:38.716:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 | 2014-08-06 13:19:38.817:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/opt/archiva-2.0/apps/archiva/},/opt/archiva-2.0/apps/archiva
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 | java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:85)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:72)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:367)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.deploy(ContextDeployer.java:359)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.access$000(ContextDeployer.java:82)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer$ScannerListener.fileAdded(ContextDeployer.java:107)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:336)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.doStart(ContextDeployer.java:421)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1274)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1197)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 | Caused by: 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 | java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/archiva/web/startup/ArchivaStartup : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:421)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1528)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitListener(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1893)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:85)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:72)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:367)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.deploy(ContextDeployer.java:359)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.access$000(ContextDeployer.java:82)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer$ScannerListener.fileAdded(ContextDeployer.java:107)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:336)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.doStart(ContextDeployer.java:421)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1274)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1197)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2014/08/06 13:19:38 | 2014-08-06 13:19:38.842:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Note that I have no other file in the /opt/archiva-2.0/logs folder, except archiva.pid.

I'm using the **standalone distribution** (apache-archiva-2.1.0-bin.zip) with no extra configuration.

My JAVA_HOME is set to **/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45**, as required by [the docs](http://archiva.apache.org/download.cgi).

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information on the download page is out of date. The [release notes](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/release-notes.html) for 2.1.0 says you need Java 1.7

Comment: I didn't find a way to register on their Jira, but they should definitely be warned.